# ASP.Net / MySQL Multi-level menu

Tags: asp.net, mysql, menu, multi-level

I'm trying to generate a menu web control by retrieving data from a MySQL table. I've stored all data in a DataTable but so far I'm able to do one level. I'm sure there must be a recursive function somewhere here but I don't know how to add to deeper levels.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
    public Menus(Menu menu, int menuId)
    {
        Database db = new Database("localhost", "dotnetcms", "root");
        DataTable data;

        query = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE menu_id = " + menuId + " ORDER BY `order`, parent ASC";
        queryRows = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM links WHERE menu_id = " + menuId + " ORDER BY `order`, parent ASC";

        data = db.AQuery(query);

        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            if (row[3] == DBNull.Value)
            {
                menu.Items.Add(new MenuItem(row[1].ToString()));
            }
            else
            {
                AddChildMenus(row, menu.Items[Convert.ToInt32(row[3]) - 1]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddChildMenus(DataRow dr, MenuItem parent)
    {
        parent.ChildItems.Add(new MenuItem(dr[1].ToString()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support recursive selects. With a very limited number of levels you can do it in a single query, repeatedly joining the table against itself on the parent / child id.

However a nested set model is probably your best solution.